# How can I profile what causes a CMS to load slowly? (PHP)

Tags: php

How can I profile the execution time of a custom CMS to see what causing it to load slowly?
I can't hard code a `microtime` in each section, because it will take weeks until I'll finish.

My server is running Linux with Apache.

Note: I couldn't find matching tags, so if an administrator sees this, please correct.

Thanks

Comment: What is the CMS?  Is it Drupal, Joomla, Wordpress, or...

Comment: It's a custom one..

Comment: You'll probably get better responses at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Install [NewRelic](http://newrelic.com/) for [Application Monitoring](http://newrelic.com/product/application-monitoring).  I don't have any affiliation to NewRelic, but I can tell you for sure that it's *excellent* for diagnosing performance issues and bottlenecks in code.

You get the Pro service for 14 days for free with a new account, and that *should* be long enough to diagnose your problem.  Last time I used it on a PHP project, it was so very useful that we decided to pay for it for a longer period.

I'm aware this isn't a "free" solution, but neither is the developer's time in adding debug `microtime` statements in every block and manually tracking queries through the system. This is why the small cost (and free trial) makes for a great idea just to evaluate the NewRelic system.  It worked for me in the past for this similar kind of problem.